# How to compare list and dictionary values and assign a variable

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison

I have a list with a certain amount of winners from fights, entered by the user e.g. `winners = ['Hunt', 'Nunes', 'Cormier']`

I then have a dictionary with each player's correct guess as values and their names as keys and my program then compares the list of winners with the values for each key and tells each player how many fights they guessed correctly

```
for name in player_dict:
    player_dict[name].sort()
    player_dict[name] = set(player_dict[name]) & set(winners)
    wins = (len(player_dict[name]))
    print(name + ' guessed ' + str(wins) + ' fights correctly.')
```

What I want to be able to do is give each fight a value depending on how many people guessed correctly and then use this value to determine how much of the pot each player who correctly guessed the winner of that fight will get.

EDIT: Here is the entirety of my code to help provide clarity

```
#!  python3

#fight_gambler.py - a program that lets players gamble on fights with friends

players = []
while len(players) >= 0:
    name = input('Enter a name: ')
    players.append(name)
    if name == '':
        players.pop()
        break
    else:
        pass  

player_dict = {name: [] for name in players} #creates a key for each name with that name as the key
print(player_dict)

fight_amount = int(input('How many fights are there? '))
fight_number = 1
for name in player_dict:                    #adds fight winner prediction as values to each name 

fight_number = 1

while fight_number <= fight_amount:
        answer = input(name + ', who will win fight ' + str(fight_number) + '? ')
        player_dict[name].append(answer)
        fight_number = fight_number + 1
fight_number = 1
winners = []

while fight_number <= fight_amount:                   # creates a list of fight winners
    winner = input('Who won fight ' + str(fight_number) + '? ')
    winners.append(winner)
    fight_number = fight_number + 1
winners.sort()

for name in player_dict:
    player_dict[name].sort()
    player_dict[name] = set(player_dict[name]) & set(winners)
    wins = (len(player_dict[name]))
    print(name + ' guessed ' + str(wins) + ' fights correctly.')
```

Comment: If you send `player_dict` data then people might help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following calculates the number of *correct* guess' a player in the `players` dictionary has made. If so you can do this with the `intersection()` of a `list` with a `set` of `winners`.

To add to this, a list of the winners' names is added to a running `total`, this is then converted to a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) collection (*accepts an iterable and returns a **key/value** data structure that keeps count of occurrences of the same keys found in the list*). From this we can extrapolate the necessary guessing data.

```
from collections import Counter

winners = set([['Hunt', 'Nunes', 'Cormier'])
players = {'player1': ['Nunes', 'Cormier', 'test1', 'test2'], 
'player2': ['Nunes','test1', 'test2','test3', 'test4'],  
'player3' : ['Hunt', 'Nunes', 'Cormier']}

total = []
for player, picks in players.iteritems():
    inter = winners.intersection(picks)
    total.extend(inter)  # Add to list of winner names.
    print player, 'guessed:', len(inter), 'fights correctly.'

for fighter, guess in Counter(total).iteritems():
    print fighter,'was guessed correctly',guess,'times.' if guess>1 else 'time.'
```

or you could go for a more **functional programming** approach (*inspired by user: [**@AMomchilov's**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander-momchliov) idea*).

```
players_num_correct_picks = dict((k, winners.intersection(v)) for (k, v) in players.items())
for player, picks in players_num_correct_picks.items():
    print player, 'guessed:', len(picks), 'fights correctly.'

total = Counter(item for sublist in players_num_correct_picks.values() for item in sublist)
for fighter, guess in total.items():
    print fighter,'was guessed correctly',guess,'times.' if guess>1 else 'time.'
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> player2 guessed: 1 fights correctly.
>>> player3 guessed: 3 fights correctly.
>>> player1 guessed: 2 fights correctly.
>>> Cormier was guessed correctly 2 times.
>>> Nunes was guessed correctly 3 times.
>>> Hunt was guessed correctly 1 time.
```

Comment: basically I'm looking for the program to count how many times the winner of each fight was guessed correctly

Comment: Updated it @LukeBray